# how to make DLL of existing C++ project in Visual Studio 17

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll

I have my C++ project and I want to open this project through my other c# project using DLL. Currently this is executable project(.exe) but I want to convert it into DLL. so, how can I do this?

I changed the general configuration to dll but after I build the solution the following error is occurred
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line Suppression State Error    LNK1306 DLL entry point "int __clrcall main(cli::array^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01EAPE$AAVString@System@@@Z) cannot be managed; compile to native Ellipsis2 C:\Users\Dhruvin\Downloads\Compressed\Ellipsis2\Ellipsis2\Test.obj 1

Comment: If im not mistaken you can just reference the project without having to convert it to a DLL

Comment: I just changed the Configuration type .exe to .dll in General Configuration properties. But now when I Build the solution, that error is occur.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1306 DLL entry point "int __clrcall main(cli::array<System::PE$AAVString >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01EAPE$AAVString@System@@@Z) cannot be managed; compile to native Ellipsis2 C:\Users\Dhruvin\Downloads\Compressed\Ellipsis2\Ellipsis2\Test.obj 1

this error is occur